# p:submenu clickable

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Is there any possibility to make a `<p:submenu>` clickable and accordingly to fire an action?

This is how my code looks like, I would like to be able to click on the submenu as well.

```html
<p:menu styleClass="menu">
    <p:submenu label="Meine Versicherungen">
        <p:menuitem value="Polizzen"  />
        <p:menuitem value="Schäden" />
        <p:menuitem value="TopKunde-Info" />
    </p:submenu>
    <p:submenu label="Meine Daten">
        <p:menuitem value="Kundendaten" />
        <p:menuitem value="Benutzerdaten" />
    </p:submenu>
    <p:submenu label="Diverses">
        <p:menuitem value="Postfach"/>
        <p:menuitem value="eKommunikationsvereinb." />
        <p:menuitem value="Transport" />
    </p:submenu>
</p:menu>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the PrimeFaces docs there is no straightforward way... There are no callbacks like `onclick` or something

But if you really want to call some js functions on your `p:submenu` you can use the following hack

add `styleClass` to your `p:submenu` , like this

```
<p:submenu styleClass="myMeineClass" label="Meine Versicherungen">
```

and in js use jQuery `bind` (for example)

```
$(".myMeineClass").bind("click",function(){ alert("myMeineClass was clicked"); });
```