# slideMenu and selected submenu value

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a tree of categories (types) to be showed inside a `<p:slideMenu>`, I want to select the category showed inside the label of `<p:submenu>`, and not show its subcategories (contained inside a list of `<p:menuitem>` tags).

Is there any way to solve this issue, for example add a button in front of each `<p:submenu>` and when I click the button the current `<p:submenu>` is selected and its value is sent to a backing bean, and when I click on the label contained inside `<p:submenu>` the subcategories will be shown.

I am using primefaces 3.5.

Comment: Post some code please

Comment: Hi welcome to stack overflow. Please show us your efforts so we can pinpoint the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [p:submenu clickable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479873/psubmenu-clickable)